# Why are two 'com-' prefixes in 'concomitant'?

Tags: etymology

> [[ Etymonline for 'concomitant (adj.)' ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=concomitant&searchmode=none) ... from ***com-* "with, together"** (see [com-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=com-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *`comitari`* "join as a companion," from comes (genitive comitis) "companion" (see [count](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=count&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)).
>
> [[ Etymonline for 'count (n.)' ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=count&allowed_in_frame=0) ... from ***COM-* "with"** (see com-) + stem of ire "to go" (see ion). ...

For want of discrimination, I bolded the later 2nd *com-* prefix, and capitalised the first one.
How and why was a second ***com-*** fastened onto *`comitari`*?
Is the 2nd redundant? If the 2nd is necessary, what does it mean especially?

What are some formal terms describing this phenomenon?

Comment: There are not "two com- prefixes in comcomitant (sic)"; there is one "con" and one "com" in concomitant (sic recte).

Answer (score 4):

Lexicalization. At an earlier stage, the combination *kom+i-* might be derived productively and the meaning can be computed compositionally. But it takes on a different meaning from "go with", and it gets reanalyzed as *comitare*. Reanalysis wipes out the memory of the word having come from *kom+i-*, and a millenium later someone re-prefixes this verb.

Comment: Right. Once something is lexicalized, it's reified and its older parts aren't accessible. That's why (for one example) the Greek roots _helico-_ 'spiral' and _-pter_ 'wing' that make up _helicopter_ have been rebroken at a different joint to form the English forms _heli-_ and _-copter_, as in _helipad_ and _cargo copter_.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please clarify `it takes on a different meaning from "go with"`? Which different meaning?